# OCaml - Creating a function which prompts for floats and returns a list of floats

Tags: ocaml

I'm teaching myself OCaml and I sometimes need to create a function where I'm not really sure what the proper solution should be. Here's one that I'm a little confused about.

I need a function that will prompt the user for individual float values and return everything entered in a float list. I can create this function but I'm not sure if its the proper/best way to do it in Ocaml.

Here's my attempt.

```
let rec get_floats() =
match
(
    try Some(read_float())
    with
    | float_of_string -> None
)
with
| None -> []
| Some s -> s :: get_floats();;
```

This code works buts I'm at a loss deciding if its a 'proper OCaml' solution. Note, to exit the function and return the float list just enter a non-integer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I hope that) this is a simple peephole rewrite involving no thought whatsoever of the function in your question:

```
let rec get_floats() =
  try 
    let f = read_float() in (* as suggested by Martin Jambon *)
    f :: (get_floats())
  with
    | float_of_string -> []
```

The idea I tried to apply here is that you do not need to convert the success/failure of `read_float` into an option that you immediately match: just do what you have to do with the value read, and let the `with` handle the failure case.

---

Now that I think of it, I should point out that in both your question and my rewrite, `float_of_string` is a fresh variable. If you meant to match a specific exception, you failed at it: all exception constructors, like datatype constructors, are Capitalized. You might as well have written `with _ ->` instead of `with float_of_string ->`, and a recent version of OCaml with all warnings active should tell you that your function (or mine) binds a variable `float_of_string` without ever using it.

Comment: And this is why I posted the problem. Thanks for the simplified version of what I was trying to do. I don't know why its so hard for me to think in a OCaml way.

Comment: I just tried your solution and found that it didn't work. The function get_floats() won't return when the user enters a non-float value.

Comment: Unspecified evaluation order. Try instead: let x = read_float() in x :: get_floats()

Comment: Thanks, the updated version works but I really find it hard to understand how you arrived at it. Are you claiming that the :: operator doesn't specify evaluation order?

Comment: @user3158810 That is exactly it. Generally speaking, (curried) functions of several arguments in OCaml evaluate their arguments in unspecified order. That is, if you have `e1 e2 e3` where each of `e1`, `e2`, and `e3` is an expression, they can be reduced to values v1, v2 and v3  in any order before the application takes place (if the program is well-typed, v1 will reduce to a function or never terminate). The difference is only visible with side-effects in one of `e1`, `e2` or `e3` (and exceptions **are** side-effects)

Comment: @user3158810 Illustration: in the toplevel, `(print_int 1; fun x y -> x + y) (print_int 2; 4) (print_int 3; 5) ;;` shows `321- : int = 9` (but it could be different in the native compiler)

Comment: @PascalCuoq I have no idea what your trying to demonstrate in the above example. I understand where the 321- comes from but I'm at a lose how the function fun x y -> x + y is applied to 4 and 5. I think you provided an example beyond my current OCaml skills.

Comment: @user3158810 This example is of the form `e1 e2 e3` with `e1` evaluating to the addition function, `e2` evaluating to `4` and `e3` evaluating to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. This works.

```
let rec get_floats() =
try
    let x = read_float() in
    x :: get_floats()
with
| _ -> [];;
```

List.iter (fun x -> print_endline(string_of_float x)) (get_floats());;